# Pandas read_html missing some tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas read_html to find all tables in a specific webpage; however, the process seems to be missing some of the tables.

Here is the webpage: https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/mclsstc/mcls1.htm

and here is my simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = pd.read_html("https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/mclsstc/mcls1.htm")

print(len(df_list))
```

This process finds 9 of the 17 tables. How can I use this method to find all the tables?

Note: if I try this on pages for other geographical areas, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `pd.read_html` function can't find all table tags.
I can suggest you to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) packages for this task. You can install it via `pip install <package_name>`.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/mclsstc/mcls1.htm")
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
tables = bs_obj.findAll('table')
dfs = list()
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)
```

In result, you'l have all tables (in DataFrame type) in dfs list.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. With minor adjustment for Python 3, this worked perfect.