# Python Pandas read_html function missing some tables from Pro-Football-Reference

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read a lot of tables from a specific webpage in Python, and am struggling a bit. My first go at this was using Pandas read_html due to it's simplicity; so for example, I will be using this website:

https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/

For read_html, I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019'

allDfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)

print(len(allDfs))
```

Which yields a count of tables of 2. However, if you follow that URL, you will see that there are many more than 2 tables, and they aren't being caught by the read_html function.

Next, I tried using requests and BeautifulSoup, with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

allTables = soup.find_all('table')

print(len(allTables))
```

This also outputs only 2 tables. I take this step a little bit further, and try to inspect one of the tables further down in the raw HTML that exists but is not being found; in this example, I will use the "Team Offense" table, which has a table tag and an id "team_stats". However, this code returns 0 tables found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

allTables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={"id":"team_stats"})

print(len(allTables))
```

Finally, I came to stackoverflow, and found the following question/response:
[Pandas read_html missing some tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533491/pandas-read-html-missing-some-tables)

So following these directions, I use urllib.request in conjuction with BeautifulSoup and Pandas and should be able to get the result...except I *still* only get 2 tables back:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html_text = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/#all_team_stats")
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text,features='lxml')
tables = bs_obj.findAll('table')
dfs = list()
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)

print(len(dfs))
```

Can anyone here help me figure out why any of these methods are not working? You can clearly see that there are many more than 2 tables on this page, but none of these methods are able to find them.

Comment: The page is generated dynamically, likely using ajax. That means the page doesn't fully load until visited by an actual browser. You probably need something like selenium browser automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tables are "hidden" within the comments in `HTML`, but, as stated by other users they appear to be loaded dynamically.

Anyhow, here's how to get them all:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

response = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2019/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each:
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each)[0])
        except:
            continue

print(tables[-1].loc[1:])
```

This, for examples, prints the last table `Drive Averages`:

```
   Unnamed: 0_level_0    Unnamed: 1_level_0  ... Average Drive      
                   Rk                    Tm  ...          Time   Pts
1                 2.0     Carolina Panthers  ...          2:25  1.74
2                 3.0  New England Patriots  ...          2:40  1.97
3                 4.0         New York Jets  ...          2:27  1.23
4                 5.0      Seattle Seahawks  ...          2:40  2.07
5                 6.0   Philadelphia Eagles  ...          2:50  1.96
6                 7.0   Pittsburgh Steelers  ...          2:28  1.40
7                 8.0         Buffalo Bills  ...          2:35  1.63
8                 9.0       New York Giants  ...          2:29  1.75
9                10.0      Tennessee Titans  ...          2:28  2.02
10               11.0      Los Angeles Rams  ...          2:31  1.98
11               12.0         Detroit Lions  ...          2:33  1.77
12               13.0   San Francisco 49ers  ...          2:46  2.44
13               14.0      Cleveland Browns  ...          2:36  1.83
14               15.0        Miami Dolphins  ...          2:32  1.61
15               16.0    Cincinnati Bengals  ...          2:37  1.49
16               17.0     Arizona Cardinals  ...          2:29  2.02
17               18.0     Green Bay Packers  ...          2:51  2.11
18               19.0  Jacksonville Jaguars  ...          2:45  1.63
19               20.0   Washington Redskins  ...          2:28  1.50
20               21.0        Dallas Cowboys  ...          2:42  2.43
21               22.0         Chicago Bears  ...          2:46  1.51
22               23.0       Atlanta Falcons  ...          2:51  2.12
23               24.0    New Orleans Saints  ...          2:59  2.50
24               25.0     Minnesota Vikings  ...          2:40  2.29
25               26.0        Denver Broncos  ...          2:43  1.60
26               27.0        Houston Texans  ...          2:51  2.18
27               28.0    Indianapolis Colts  ...          2:52  2.02
28               29.0      Baltimore Ravens  ...          3:21  2.95
29               30.0       Oakland Raiders  ...          3:00  1.83
30               31.0    Kansas City Chiefs  ...          2:52  2.59
31               32.0  Los Angeles Chargers  ...          3:05  2.06
32                NaN          League Total  ...          2:41  1.94

[32 rows x 12 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For those reading this post in the future, the original "two" tables that pandas was able to read with read_html is not included with those code, but obviously that is easy enough already. With this comment as well as the original code I am able to get all the tables I was looking for.